# Override a class doesn't work for his child?

Tags: magento2, overrides

I want to override this class : 'Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer'
This class has a child like : 'Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer'

So i use     `<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" type="Custom\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" />`

It's works only when i use the parent class ( Cart\Item\Renderer ). but when i instantiate the child i can't use my custom function.
Is there something else to do ?
I have to override all the child class ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the block using layout XML. In this case check how the Bundle module defines a custom renderer for bundle-type products:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Bundle/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml.

You would need to do the same, i.e. define a custom block class that extends `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer` - as per this:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Bundle/Block/Checkout/Cart/Item/Renderer.php.